# Number of functions from Karnaugh maps

Tags: karnaugh-map

Givn a function \$f(w,x,y,z)=\Sigma(1,4,5,7,13)+\Sigma_\phi(0,8,9,12,15)\$
I set up a karnaugh map for it, and my question is:
Other than counting, what is the best way to calculate how many \$f\$ are there?
I know this is somewhat a combinatorics question, but since the karnaugh map works in a bit change not all combinations are valid functions.

Comment: What are Σ and Σϕ?

Comment: Sum of products of the minterms and the dont cares of the function.

Comment: I don't know what that is supposed to mean. And if they're functions, why do their parameters have nothing to do with w, x, y or z?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

Comment: I know what a Karnaugh map is. I don't know how Σ(1,4,5,7,13) is "the sum of the products of the minterms" and likewise how Σϕ(0,8,9,12,15) is "the sum of the products of the dont-cares".

Comment: What he's saying is that this is not a standard notation.

Comment: Just curious, but do you mean \$\Sigma_\emptyset\$?

Comment: What is the standard notation then? I was under the impression that THIS is the standard notation. Anyway, I meant that the sum of minterms m1 m4 m5 m7 m13, and the sum of dont cares m0 m8 m9 m12 m15

Comment: I never took anything higher than a freshman level digital logic course, so maybe that's a more mathematical or computational logic way of representing them. We always just wrote it out explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't place any constraints on it, there are infinite functions, I believe.

(because \$A\overline A\$ can be added to anything, ad infinitum, for example)